# Render Jinja after jQuery AJAX request to Flask

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a web application that gets dynamic data from **Flask** when a **select** element from HTML is changed. of course that is done via **jquery ajax**. No probs here I got that.

The problem is, the dynamic data **- that is sent by Flask -**, is a list of objects from the database **Flask-sqlalchemy**.

Of course the data is sent as **JSON** from **Flask**.

I'd like to iterate through those objects to display their info using **Jinja**.

### HTML

```
<select id="#mySelect">
    <option value="option1" id="1">Option 1 </option>
    <option value="option2" id="1">Option 2 </option> 
    <option value="option3" id="3">Option 3 </option>
</select>
```

### jQuery

```
$('body').on('change','#mySelect',function(){
   var option_id = $('#mySelect').find(':selected').attr('id');
   $.ajax({
     url: "{{ url_for('_get_content') }}",
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "json",
     data: {'option_id':option_id},
     success: function(data){
       data = data.data;
      /* HERE I WANT TO ITERATE THROUGH THE data LIST OF OBJECTS */
     }

   });
});
```

### Flask

```
@app.route('/_get_content/')
def _get_content():
    option_id = request.form['option_id']
    all_options = models.Content.query.filter_by(id=option_id)
    return jsonify({'data': all_options})
```

#### PS : I know that jinja gets rendered first so there is no way to assign jQuery variables to Jinja. So how exactly am I going to iterate through the data list if I can't use it in Jinja ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Okay, I got it.

Simply, I made an external **html** file and added the required **jinja** template to it.

```
{% for object in object_list %}
   {{object.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

then in my **Flask** file I literally returned the **render_template** response to the **jquery** ( which contained the **HTML** I wanted to append )

```
objects_from_db = getAllObjects()
return jsonify({'data': render_template('the_temp.html', object_list=objects_from_db)}
```

And then simply append the HTML from the response to the required div to be updated.

Edit: Here's the link to a Youtube video that I made which explains the process:
https://youtu.be/ZEv4AjvoQOk

Comment: I need to do something exactly like this but am getting confused, on where you say `And then simply append the HTML from the response to the required div to be updated.` At the moment I have my `index.html` file and then I render `the_temp.html` file with my data passed to it, still getting confused on how to display the code.

Comment: A while has passed on this but I will try my best to explain. first you send the `ajax` request with `jquery` then you process the request in `Flask`. when the processing is done, you need to send an `HTML Page` back to the `jquery`. you can do this by returning the `render_template` response to the `jquery`. you then use `jquery` to append that response to the `HTML` dom. like `$('#jquery_resp').append(response);`. hope that makes sense, if not, comment with what u need and I will try to help. check my YouTube channel for tuts on Flask:https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCR06GVwwhcsBNtnZ9-xsiNw

Comment: Thanks but still a bit confused. As at the moment I am only using `ajax` `GET` as on a button click this refreshes the content that I am getting from mysql. The part you say return the response this is fine, I am logging my response to the console and I can see a list of objects (all the data from the mysql). You say append it to `HTML` dom but how will it loop through all the results?

Comment: You don't loop through anything in `jQuery`, you actually create a `jinja template file`. like this `<ul> {% for result in all_results%} <li> {{result}}</li> {% endfor %}`. then you call `render_template` from `Flask` and return whatever value `render_template` returns. to make it simple, `return jsoninfy({'data': render_template('all_results.hml.j2'})'. makes sense? if not, tell me and I will try to make up a vid discussing this topic today.

Comment: Hi sorry still confused. If you could please make a video on this, I been struggling with it for days now!

Comment: Okay. I'm working on the video as we speak. will post the link to the vid after it has been published. stay tuned!

Comment: here is the vid that I promised : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJdQxS3ZpNI&feature=youtu.be

I hope it makes better sense now. if not, contact me on my Facebook page : 
https://www.facebook.com/m41kdev3lops

Good Luck!

Comment: @M41kDev3lops Thanks for the video! Still very helpful! :0)

Comment: @petezurich thank you for your support. it's very nice to see such an old thread is still helping people :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending data using json you don't need to use Jinja2. You can simply try something like this:

```
@app.route('/_get_content/')
def _get_content():
    option_id = request.form['option_id']
    all_options = models.Content.query.filter_by(id=option_id)
    return jsonify({'data': [option.name for option in all_options]})
```

or define a method in your model something like `to_json` that returns a field or dictionary or ... and call it in your view.

```
@app.route('/_get_content/')
def _get_content():
    option_id = request.form['option_id']
    all_options = models.Content.query.filter_by(id=option_id)
    return jsonify({'data': [option.to_json() for option in all_options]})
```

Comment: How do I call the json objects in with my view? if I'm using the template engine to insert different values? Can you demonstrate an example of calling the json value in your view with html tags