# How to detect a user has cancelled a page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a web page with a basic form. There's a non-negligible wait time between clicking "submit" and the page reloading with results, so I added a little spinner while the user waits.

It's pretty straight forward, here is the HTML:

```
<div id="loadingBox" style="display:none;">
    <!---put the actual loader here--->
</div>
```

Here is the basic event handler for making the spinner visible after the user clicks submit:

```
$("#submitButton").submit(function(e)
{
    $("#loadingBox").css('display', 'block');
});
```

The problem is that the user can click submit, make the box appear, and then hit escape or click the browser button to cancel the page load, and the spinner keeps spinning.

I added this to make the spinner disappear if they hit escape:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e)
{
    if(e.keyCode == 27)
    {
        $("#loadingBox").css('display', 'none');
    }
})
```

What can I do to detect that the user has clicked the cancel page load button? I cannot find an event that fires when that button is clicked and I cannot find a ready state or other attribute that reflects it. My concern is a user clicks the cancel load button, and then the spinner doesn't go away, and the user stares at the spinner thinking the page is still doing something, but it isn't doing anything.

Comment: How about using ajax to submit. That way you can provide a cancel button(don't know why you would want to but this way you can send a response to the server(ajax again) to delete the data that was just saved, to prevent inadequacies), you can even do redirects with ajax now.

Comment: Yeah I'm in the process of converting to AJAX for this purpose. Thanks!

Comment: Do you need an answer with ajax still?

Comment: Thanks @HimanshuPant but I got it now, submitted an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved my issue.

First, I converted the page to use AJAX. I'm using Flask, and so this webpage was very helpful:
https://medium.com/@doobeh/posting-a-wtform-via-ajax-with-flask-b977782edeee

But then I needed to update the existing Jinja2 templates with the data I receive from AJAX. I ended up doing this by calling jsonify on the render_template function, as discussed here:
[Render Jinja after jQuery AJAX request to Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40391566/render-jinja-after-jquery-ajax-request-to-flask)

But then my buttons for collapsing/expanding parts of the templated table were not working, as it turns out events only work on things that were present when the page loaded. So I had to delegate the event to allow items added after the fact to trigger the events my jquery was listening for, as discussed here:
https://aiocollective.com/blog/click-doesn-t-work-after-ajax-load-jquery/

I hope these links are helpful to someone else!

Answer (score 0):

listen for the [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) event.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
  alert("How dare you leave this page?!");
});
```

Comment: I added a snippet like the above to my code and told it to log "test" to the console. Unfortunately I am only seeing this log occur when the submit button is clicked, not when the cancel load browser button is clicked. As a result, it is immediately setting loader display to none instead of waiting for a load cancel before setting it to none.